# Ubuntu for VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

New kid on the block...
Is there an "OVA" for any recent release to use in Virtualbox?
Or can I just use the "desktop" version?

I don't know what the difference is between an ISO and an OVA
I understand what the ISO is for but what does an OVA do?

Comment: An OVA contains a pre-built image of an OS; an ISO is a disk image, usually containing installation media.

Comment: Can I use the ISO for virtualbox? I'm not finding an OVA

Comment: I usually start with an ISO when making a VBox VM. VBox will  let you boot the ISO live and then install.

Comment: thank you! I'll continue on....

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - added.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably download the ISO image and install that to a VirtualBox VM (this way you can setup the VM and not have any preinstalled usernames, passwords, softwares, and or hostname. Also, if you install from an ISO Image, the machine will have the latest updates, which is a plus. Do you specifically need an OVA image?

Comment: I didn't need an ova, didn't understand what one was, I do now.

Comment: Oh ok. Well hopefully we all helped you with your problem!

Answer (score 1):

(Italicized definition is from the fileinfo.com website)

*An OVA file is a virtual appliance used by virtualization applications such as VMware Workstation and Oracle VM Virtualbox. It is a package that contains files used to describe a virtual machine, which includes an .OVF descriptor file, optional manifest (.MF) and certificate files, and other related files.*

While there are plenty of OVAs available for Virtualbox - I've personally used ones for Windows 7/8/10 and Solaris 11 - it's so easy to install Ubuntu that there's really no need for one.

*An ISO file is a common CD or DVD disc image format based on the ISO-9660 standard. It contains an exact duplicate of data from the original disc, which includes the data saved on the disc as well as the filesystem information, such as directory structures, file attributes, and boot code. ISO files are often used for making copies of CDs and DVDs.*

As stated above, Ubuntu install media is usually obtained by downloading, then installing from an ISO file, either by creating a bootable USB or, in the case of Virtualbox, using the ISO file to boot from directly.